# Moviepy distorting concatenated (portrait) videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, video-processing, moviepy

Trying to concatenate various "Portrait" videos I took with my mobile phone using the moviepy library. But for some reason, the result is a distorted video. As a TEST CASE, I have even tried to read JUST ONE video clip and re-write it using the concatenate_videoclips method and it still produces a distorted result.

Here is a sample frame from a test video taken with my mobile (resolution on disk: 1920 x 1080 which obviously includes the black background):

[image: Text]

Here is the same frame captured from the output video (resolution maintained at 1920 x 1080 but without the black background => distorted image):

[image: Text]

Here is the (very simple) code snippet I used:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips


video_0 = VideoFileClip("test_vid.mp4")

concatenated_clip = concatenate_videoclips([video_0], method="compose")  # same result if method="chain"
concatenated_clip.write_videofile("test_vid_concat.mp4")
```

I can't figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `moviepy` version `1.0.3`: the ffmpeg reader doesn't take rotation metadata into account for videos captured on phones. The bug was noted in:

[Video file clip width and height do not take rotation metadata into account #1663](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1663)

and a fix provided in May of this year on the `master` branch:

[Take into account rotation metadata to define video size #577](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/577)

Version `1.0.3` is still the latest version on PyPI (i.e. version installed by `pip`), so you need to install the master branch (`git clone` the repo and run `py setup.py install` in the source folder) to get the fix.

I ran into the same issue and installing the master branch fixed it for me.

Be forewarned: `moviepy` is still pretty out of date. It relies on `numpy == 1.20` and so you will have to use a lot of older packages. I highly recommend installing in a virtual environment.